# Naming methods to generic arguments

Tags: java, generics, naming

I am going over some code and I am adding some interfaces so i can make sure all the classes follow the same basic guidelines.
Now I have an interface called Uni < T > which takes exactly one generic argument.
Say I have a class which implements Uni< Foo > then I would like that class to have this method `public foo getFoo(){};`
Is there any way to add this method to the interface? I would prefer if i could do something like this in my interface `public T getT();` and the second T gets replaced by the generic argument.

I can't just call it "get" because I would like some classes to implement multiple versions of Uni. `public Example implements Uni<Foo1>,Uni<Foo2>`

I know I can give the function 'get' an argument Foo or Class but I'd rather not so I thought I'd ask here.
(I would also mess up the naming convection if i did this)

Comment: *"I would like some classes to implement multiple versions of Uni"* That's impossible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible. And as generics in Java are implemented via erasure (i.e. dropped by the compiler), you will also not be able to implement multiple versions in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible with java but you can do it like this

```
public interface example<T> {
   public void yourmethod(T object);
}
```

make the interface according to the generic type you want.